# Zoom any DOM element

Tags: jquery, zooming

I have those element:

```
<div id="foo">
    <div class="foo1">Element</div>
    <div class="foo2">Element zoomed</div>
</div>
```

I'm wondering if is there a way for me to zoom any element in DOM.

Js example:

```
$(function(){
    $('#foo .foo2').zoom();
});
```

I just googled it and didn't find a good answer for that. Some help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Not 'zoom' but CSS3 transforms will do it for you.  Click the button below to see in action.

```css
.foo2 {
    -ms-transform: scale(2); /* IE 9 */
    -webkit-transform: scale(2); /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    transform: scale(2);
    transform-origin: left; 
}
```

```html
<div id="foo">
    <div class="foo1">Element</div>
    <div class="foo2">Element zoomed</div>
</div>
```